# Quickest way to write to Word document from Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am transforming Excel data into a Word file from the Excel file's VBA.

I have included Word references and can produce the file but it runs very slowly! I wonder if anyone has tips on the fastest way to write to Word from Excel VBA?

It writes the same data to the Word document 25 times in a loop to get an idea of the time taken. 25 writes takes about 10 seconds on my laptop so you can imagine when I try to run it on full reports it runs very slow!

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My pseudo code for the actual write to Word:

```
  add the text at the current selection
  select the text just added
  set the style to that desired for the text
  move the selection to the end of the document for next time
  add a line break for formatting
```

My code - Write_to_File is the problematic subroutine and it seems that oSelection.EndKey is the main bottle neck:

```
Option Explicit

Private sFileName As String
Private oWord As Word.Application
Private oDoc As Word.Document
Private oSelection As Word.Selection

Private lWords As Long

Public Sub Init(sFileNameIn As String)
    sFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & sFileNameIn & ".doc"
End Sub

Public Sub Delete_Existing()
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If fso.FileExists(sFileName) Then fso.DeleteFile sFileName
End Sub

Public Function Open_File() As Boolean
    If Copy_Word_Template(sFileName) Then
        Set oWord = New Word.Application
        oWord.Visible = False ' ######## False for speed when development done
        Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(sFileName)
        Set oSelection = oWord.Selection
        ' delete the styles guidance
        oDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Delete
        lWords = oDoc.Words.Count
        Open_File = True
    Else
        Open_File = False
    End If
End Function

Public Sub Write_To_File(sText As String, Optional sStyle As String = "No Spacing")
    ' add the text:
    oSelection.TypeText sText
    ' select back all the words we just added and format:
    oSelection.MoveLeft Unit:=WdUnits.wdWord, Count:=oDoc.Words.Count - lWords, Extend:=WdMovementType.wdExtend
    oSelection.Style = oDoc.Styles(sStyle)
    ' move back to the end of the document:
    oSelection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    ' insert a carriage return:
    oSelection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak
    ' remember how many words we have for next time:
    lWords = oDoc.Words.Count ' removoing this GREATLY increased the execution time
End Sub

Public Sub Close_File()
    oDoc.SaveAs2 sFileName
    oDoc.Close True
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    oWord.Quit
    Set oWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: it is slow because you are using the `Selection` object. Use a [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range) object instead, e.g. `Document.Content`, `Document.Paragraphs.First.Range`, `Document.Paragraphs.Last.Range`

Comment: Moreover, you're opening a document, then deleting its content, instead of creating a new document from a suitably-designed template [per Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(TemplateName)] that wouldn't require anything to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks @Timothy. You were right - I replaced the code with:     `oDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertAfter sText`
`oDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = sStyle`
`oDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertAfter Chr(10)`     
And it rand a lot faster. The only problem is sometimes the `.Style` is ignored and then I stop in the debugger and try to force it Word simply ignores it without an error and retains the existing style. Any ideas why I might be having issues setting Style?

Comment: Thanks @macropod but it is a design issue to have an actual template in the folder for useability design so the manager can see and edit the styles that will be used. The overhead of doing it this way is very small compared to the slow method I had of inserting the text via Selection instead of Range. Appreciate your comment.

Comment: You seem not to understand the difference between a *template* and a *document*. Documents are not templates in Word parlance. In any event, Styles in a template can readily be modified from any document based on it. It seems some basic tuition is how to use Word properly wouldn't go astray.